# Limit the size dynamoDB primary Key using typescript

Tags: amazon-web-services, typescript, amazon-dynamodb

I am building an application with ionic3 and AWS lanbda, where i use dynamodb for my database, the primary key generated as the "Id" ( in my case "groupId" ) of the table is too long `afc9c380-db7d-11e7-a2c5-3bce7c435d3e` I would like to know if there is a way to limit the no of digits to 6 characters? Thank you

**My typescript code** - "groupId is auto Genrated"

```
addGroup(form) {
 this.submitted = true;
 if (form && this.formData.name) {
  let group = {
    name: this.formData.name,
    description: this.formData.description,
    profileImageURI: this.profileImageURI,
    userId: this.globals.getUserId(),
    imageUrl: this.formData.imageUrl
  };
  this.globals.displayLoader("Adding...");
  this.client.getClient().groupsCreateByUserId(this.globals.getUserId(), group).subscribe(
    (data) => {
      this.globals.dismissLoader();
      this.globals.displayToast(`Group successfully added.`);
      this.navCtrl.pop();
    },
    (err) => {
      this.globals.dismissLoader();
      this.globals.displayAlert('Error encountered',
        `An error occurred when trying to add the group. Please check the console logs for more information.`);
      console.error(err);
    }
  );
 }
 this.globals.dismissLoader();
}
```

Comment: This looks more like a TypeScript question than a DynamoDB question. Where do you generate groupID from?

Comment: @smcstewart i need to generate random 6 digit code

Comment: Yes. You should try to do that in Typescript. DynamoDB doesn’t provide you with IDs, therefore, it’s not really a DynamoDB question.

Comment: @smcstewart any solitions for it?

Comment: I’m not a Typescript dev. I’d use a random number generator, convert to string, then shorten to desired length. Or I’d use a UUID then shorten that. Whichever way you do it, make sure you’re code will cope with potential duplicate keys.